# How to display only Categories in the legend present in the data

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, visualization, legend

I have a data frame as below:

[image]

In the above dataframe, `'Month'` is an ordered `Categorical` column defined as:

```
cats = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April','May','June', 'July', 'August','September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
month_gr['Month'] = pd.Categorical(month_gr['Month'], cats, ordered = True)
```

using Seaborn barplot:

```
ax = sns.barplot(data = month_gr, x = 'Item Name', y = 'Total', hue = 'Month')
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation= 90, ha = 'right')
```

Outputs:
[image]

The legend above displays all 12 months of the `Categorical` column. I want to display the legend for only 4 months `['June', 'July', 'August', 'September']`, as my data contains only these 4 months. Is there a way to dynamically control the legend so it displays only the available `Categories` passed to `data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a list of "used months" and then set that list as `hue_order`. This also ensures that only those months will take up space for the bars.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

month_col = ['June'] * 5 + ['July'] * 5 + ['August'] * 5 + ['September'] * 7
month_gr = pd.DataFrame({'Month': month_col,
                         'Item Name': [*'abcdebdefgbcefgabcdefg'],
                         'Total': np.random.randint(100, 1000, len(month_col))})

cats = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
month_gr['Month'] = pd.Categorical(month_gr['Month'], cats, ordered=True)

used_months = [m for m in cats if m in month_gr['Month'].to_list()]

ax = sns.barplot(data=month_gr, x='Item Name', y='Total',
                 hue='Month', hue_order=used_months, palette=sns.color_palette("Set2"))
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Also, I think `used_months = month_gr.Month.unique()` is a better pandas option. Maybe it didn't work when passed to `hue_order=` in 2020, but it does work now.

Answer (score 0):

While [the answer by johanc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64838001/6673446) solves the problem, I'd like to highlight out another approach removing the categories not required with [pandas.Series.cat.remove_unused_categories](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.remove_unused_categories.html).

This alternative is useful in the case one doesn't need the information about the categories anymore (In case the plotted dataframe is just a view to another, this would cause problems).

The following achieves the same result as the linked answer:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

month_col = ['June'] * 5 + ['July'] * 5 + ['August'] * 5 + ['September'] * 7
month_gr = pd.DataFrame({'Month': month_col,
                         'Item Name': [*'abcdebdefgbcefgabcdefg'],
                         'Total': np.random.randint(100, 1000, len(month_col))})

cats = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
month_gr['Month'] = pd.Categorical(month_gr['Month'], cats, ordered=True)
# this differs from the accepted solution
month_gr["Month"] = month_gr["Month"].cat.remove_unused_categories()
ax = sns.barplot(data=month_gr, x='Item Name', y='Total', hue='Month', palette=sns.color_palette("Set2"))
plt.show()
```

With this solution, the categories are removed and one doesn't have to pass the `hue_order`.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add on @Nico's answer: you can also consider to change the column type to string, so you won't need to deal with unused categories. This is probably the easiest solution if you don't mind having a different column type or creating a new column/dataframe.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35089303)